# How to create NotificationManager Policy correctly?

Tags: android, notificationmanager

I am facing a problem with the NotificationManager Policy.
Let's say I just want to be interrupted by alarms. Then I specify that as the Category (NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_CATEGORY_ALARMS) but what values should I pass to create the Policy? I am talking about the priorityCallSenders, and the priorityMessageSenders. No calls and no messages are allowed, only alarms, so why should I have to specify a value for them?
The available values are:

```
PRIORITY_SENDERS_ANY
PRIORITY_SENDERS_CONTACTS
PRIORITY_SENDERS_STARRED
```

Which one should I use? The code results messy and confusing if I specify I want only alarms BUT then use the constant PRIORITY_SENDERS_ANY.

For you to remember, here I paste the call to create the Policy:

```
myPolicy = new NotificationManager.Policy(NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_CATEGORY_ALARMS, iCallsPrioritySenders, iMessagesPrioritySenders);
myNotificationManager.setNotificationPolicy(myPolicy);
```

On the other had, and I suspect that the issue might come from here, I am not able to set this values correctly in Xiaomi.
I have tried in Huawei and Android Emulator setting a value like this (even when it is not allowed by Android documentation):

```
NotificationManager.Policy(NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_CATEGORY_ALARMS, -1, -1);
```

and it works well with both. But the problem is with Xiaomi. For some reason, calls/messages are always accepted and I am not able to disable calls. It looks like must be Any, Contacts or Starred.

Any light in this issue and the right values to pass?